# How to change queryParams without triggering subscribe?

Tags: angular

Hi building angular app with multi routes.

Navigate to a page > queryParams trigger the subscribe.

when im in the page i need change the queryParams inside the page but not to trigger the subscribe function again. (because i dont want the data to reload again because i have already the data when i navigate to the page,i want only to change the params without trigger subscribe so if the user hit refresh the page will reload with the correct url and the subscribe function will work as a new navigation to the page)

i know i can use snapshot but im preferring using optional attributes.

and ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when im in the page i need change the queryParams inside the page but not to trigger the subscribe function again.

One solution would be to, inside the component, subscribe not to query params, but only to the first emitted value:

```
const mySubscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams // or queryParamMap
    .pipe(
        take(1)
    )
    .subscribe(//...
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there already has been an excepted answer, but there might be another option. In your .ts-file import

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

So I'm going to use an example based on some code that was written in a project.

Let's say you have a query-param that you use for some logic like, and that is linked (bound) to an inputfield in the .html-file

```
_searchTerm: string;


get searchTerm() { return this._searchTerm; }
    set searchTerm(value: string) {
        this._searchTerm = value;
        // this._fetchData();
        this.replaceState();
  }
```

Meaning every time the user types a single letter in that field, the searchTerm-value changes, but we're also going to change the url displayed in the browser without triggering a navigation/subscription, with the replaceState-method, like

```
replaceState(replaceString: string = this._searchTerm) { this.location.replaceState('artwork/overview', '?_searchTerm='+replaceString);}
```

and the artwork/overview is actually a string-fragment that was used to navigate to the module and component and now the url displayed will be

```
https://(some.website.com)/artwork/overview?searchTerm=WhateverTheUserTypedIntoTheSearchbox
```

It speaks for itself that you can add as much parameters as you want.

The generated url is stored in the navigation history. So if you use the back-arrow when navigating back, you actually can use the param for data loading logic, like

```
ngOnInit() {

this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {this._searchTerm = params._searchTerm });}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same use case and I believe this is a good approach:

```js
this.activatedRoute
  .queryParams
  .pipe(
    // To skip empty object trigger 
    skip(1),
    filter(params => {
      const {
        size,
        page
      } = params;

      if (+size !== this.pageSize) {
        return true;
      }

      if (+page !== this.pageIndex) {
        return true;
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe(params => {
    // Subscriber will be triggered only if your filter allows.
  });
```

You will need a method that sets the default values on init looking for query params.

Example:

```js
getTableDefaults(): {
  pageIndex: number,
  pageSize: number
} {
  let pageIndex = 0;
  let pageSize = PAGINATION_CONFIG.limit;

  const routeTableDefaults = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;

  if (Object.keys(routeTableDefaults).length) {
    const {
      page,
      size
    } = routeTableDefaults;

    pageIndex = page;
    pageSize = size;
  }

  return {
    pageIndex,
    pageSize
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without any code examples, it's quite hard to get a grip on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you're relying on the Observable streams, mutating something without triggering the `subscribe()` to respond is impossible; it's the entire function of your Observable stream.

What you optionally could do is, on the first `subscribe()` where you get your state; you could move the state to your component locally by using `tap(data => this._data = data)` or `subscribe(data => this.data = data)` or something similar.

You can mutate the local state and have that reflect in your browser by using native browser API's. There is a good chance that the native browser API's will also trigger back `router` changes, but I'm not exactly sure how that works.